# Multiple middleware in controller Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, middleware

I want to use two middleware in `__construct` method in my controller. I was searching in google last few hours but didn't find any useful resource.

Here is my `__construct` with middleware:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('adminuser');
    $this->middleware('generaluser')->only('quizDetails','validateQuiz','attemptQuiz','submitQuiz','saveAnswer','setIndividualTime');
}
```

I want to give access those generaluser middleware method for General user.
How i do that?

Please help me to solve this issues.

Thanks

Comment: Your code does what you want. What's the problem?

Comment: Hi Rajabi, I have a AdminUser controller class with many method and admin user able to access those method. But i want to give access some method from AdminUser controller Class for GeneralUser. As like i'm ask.

Answer (score 5):

So, you need to use something like "OR" for your middleware and it does not exist. Instead, you can use [middleware parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#middleware-parameters) and do the magic inside your middleware.

Create a middleware to checking all your roles there instead of one middleware for each role.

```
use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        $roles = array_except(func_get_args(), [0,1]) // get array of your roles.

        // $request->user()->role IS AN EXAMPlE
        if (! in_array($request->user()->role, $roles)) {
            // Redirect...
        }

        return $next($request);
}
```

Next is to register it in kernel.php, routeMiddleware array:

```
'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
```

Then you can check multiple roles at the same time

```
$this->middleware('role:adminuser')->only('functionA', 'functionB');

$this->middleware('role:adminuser,guestuser')->only('functionC', 'functionD');
```

**Note:** This is an example, you can change the logic inside middleware as you wish.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your valuable ans, I want to give access same method for two user. Not different method :)

Comment: I feel something is wrong. If you need to give access to your guest users, why you want to set guestuser middleware? By default, they can access these methods.

Comment: Only two user can access those method and others user can't, Is that wrong ??

I don't know Please suggest me the right way.

Comment: You need something like "OR" for your middleware and it does not exist. Instead, you can use middleware parameters and handle the logic base on them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Could please give me some example, because i don't know how to use "OR" in middleware.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer and give you an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155052/discussion-between-md-iyasin-arafat-and-morteza-rajabi).

Comment: Hi Rajabi, Thanks for your help. You idea solved my problem, Here is my code i'm apply with you idea (https://prnt.sc/go763e),(https://prnt.sc/go75zs) , Also add a ans with you idea code :)

Comment: @MDIyasinArafat That's good. I saw your code. If you need more dynamic and safe way for checking roles and permissions, I suggest you use this package https://github.com/DynamicCodeNinja/RBAC. Do not forget to Accept and Vote Up the answer :)

Comment: Already done that :) and in this project if i will role package then it will make problem for me. But next project will use :) Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the middleware in your routes file instead inside of the construct

```
Route::middleware(['adminuser'])->group(function () {

   //Only admins can access this

    Route::get('/','Controller@method');
    Route::get('/admins','Controller@method');
});

Route::middleware(['generaluser'])->group(function () {

    // General users access this

    Route::get('/users', 'Controller@method');
    Route::get('/generalusers', 'Controller@method');
});
```

If you want to use Two middlewares at same time

```
Route::middleware(['firstMiddleWare','secondMiddleWare'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/aroute', 'Controller@method');
});
```

Routes that does not belong to a group will be available for all users

Comment: Hi Khouadja, Thanks for your valuable ans. But my problem not like that, I have a AdminUser controller class with many method and admin user able to access those method. But i want to give access some method from AdminUser controller Class for GeneralUser. As like i'm ask.

Comment: That's exactly what i answered :) u just don't get it! just put the routes u want to share in generaluser group

Comment: Oh, Sorry for that. Yes i'm didn't get it. I have done another work in my route file, that's why i don't want to use middleware in my route file and for this reason, i'm using __construct. Anyway Thanks for your info. Really i don't know it, now i know and if need any time i will apply :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `adminuser` middleware allows admin users and blocks the others, so a non-admin never reaches the `generaluser` middleware.
You could try to exclude the `generaluser` methods from the `adminuser` middleware:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('adminuser')->except('quizDetails','validateQuiz','attemptQuiz','submitQuiz','saveAnswer','setIndividualTime');
    $this->middleware('generaluser')->only('quizDetails','validateQuiz','attemptQuiz','submitQuiz','saveAnswer','setIndividualTime');
}
```

Comment: Hi Lvan, Thanks for your valuable ans. Not like that, I have a AdminUser controller class with many method and admin user able to access those all method. But i want to give access some method from AdminUser controller Class for GeneralUser. As like i'm ask.

Comment: Yes, I imagined it right after my post :-) The  go with suggestion by Achraf Khouadja, it seems the best way

Comment: Yeah, But i need to give access two user for one method, that's why i can't follow his ans :)

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks [Morteza Rajabi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2803948/morteza-rajabi) for giving me this idea, Here is the code i'm apply with his idea.

I'm create a new middleware for two user, here is code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfNotAdminUserOrGeneralUser
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'adminuser':
                if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('/');
                }
            break;
            case 'generaluser':
                if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('/');
                }
            break;
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And apply this in my controller, like this and give them access as i want.
admin user can access all method and general user can access some of them. That's mean two user can access same method.

Here is controller code:

```
    public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('adminuser')->only('index','create','edit','store','delete','trashIndex','restore','permanentlyDelete','addGroups','addGroupsStore','addQuestions','addQuestionsStore','countGroup','countQuestion');
    $this->middleware('auserorguser')->only('quizDetails','validateQuiz','attemptQuiz','submitQuiz','saveAnswer','setIndividualTime');
}
```

Thanks again Morteza Rajabi.